# Presented View Controller Status Bar Color is Different, How to Change It To Default?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a presented view controller. However its status bar color is different then its navigation bar color. How do I make sure they are same color?

Comment: write something like `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent` or whatever your barStyle is, in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` of your presented view controller

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.default` for the default status bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code, if it help:

Set same style as current viewController to viewController being presented as follows:

```
//newViewController is your ViewController

newViewController.navigationBar.barStyle = self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle;

[self presentViewController:newViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Also, If you are using a navigation controller and want to control the status bar on a per view controller basis, you'll want to subclass `UINavigationController` and implement `preferredStatusBarStyle`.

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return self.topViewController.preferredStatusBarStyle;
}
```

OR

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {

    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Make sure this function is in your **presenting view controller** and the **view controller being presented**.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 13 or later we faced with non full screen presented Controllers. In this case, you can use this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621453-modalpresentationcapturesstatusb).

Answer (score -1):

```
//change the background of status bar

UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 20);
addStatusBar.backgroundColor = bgStatus;
[self.view addSubview:addStatusBar];
```

//change the text color of status bar from black to white

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```